# read the col in the csv file and write a a row in another

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to read the column wise content of the csv file and write it row wise.

I have tried it, but I cant add the second column to second row, it is getting merged in first row itself.

```
import csv
col ={}
 with open('C:/Users/upadh/Desktop/north.csv', 'r') as f, 
  open('current.csv', 'w') as f_out:
for line in f:
 cols = line.split(',', 4)
  if len(cols) >= 4:

  col = cols[0].strip()+","
 # col = col +"\n"
  f_out.write(col)
```

1,2,3
welcome, to, Delhi
as:
1,welcome
2,to
3,Delhi

Answer (score 0):

Did you try transpose?. It may suit your requirements.

```
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4

df1_transposed = df1.transpose()
      0  1
col1  1  2
col2  3  4
```